# How to get Disk type information from VMware using pyvmomi?

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

I have to get DiskType information using python pyvmomi library, I am able to get the same through C# VMware sdk via `"Get-VM | Get-HardDisk -DiskType "Flat" | Select Parent,Name,DiskType,ScsiCanonicalName,DeviceName,Diskmode | fl"` command, which will output all the disk in vSphere/eSX with *Flat* disktype. In the respective command, I have searched for **"Flat"** *disktype* which can also be **"RawPhysical, RawVirtual, or Unknown"**. I have gone through VMware MOB properties as well but wasn't able to search for DiskType property.

Thanks

Comment: Does this link help: https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/virtual_machine_device_info.py ?

Comment: No, it doesn't help as it will not tell me disktype of my virtual disk. If I run above C# query in VMware powercli after connecting to my vSphere/eSX it will give output as:                                                    (Parent            : test,
Name              : Hard disk 1,
DiskType          : Flat/RawPhysical/RawVirtual/Unknown,
ScsiCanonicalName : xyz
DeviceName        : xyz
Diskmode          : xyz),                                                                                                                  and the shared link will not give respective info.

Comment: @justjais any update on this issue, have you got the disk type through MOB?

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over `vim.vm.config.hardware.device` and check if there's a device that has the property `backing` of type `RawDiskMappingVer1BackingInfo`, [see the docs](https://pubs.vmware.com/vi3/sdk/ReferenceGuide/vim.vm.device.VirtualDisk.RawDiskMappingVer1BackingInfo.html) for details on that object.